# How to get all text after the second to last instance of a character excluding the last instance?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following partial URL:

```
"/tennis/qatar/atp-doha-2009/hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l/"
```

I'd like to get everything after the second to last `/` and excluding the final `/` so:

```
"hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l"
```

I've got as far as:

```
re.search(r".*/(.*?/.*)", url)
```

Which gets me:

```
"hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l/"
```

But I can't figure out how to get rid of the final slash. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Might be simpler and clearer using a proper path or URL parser or just `str.split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
^.*?/([^/]*)/?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/xm1tYA/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]*                    any character except: '/' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /?                       '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

[Python code](https://tio.run/##Hc29DoIwFEDhvU/RNA5gLJeIgw6GxdHN0UjSSKE15bZe7gBPX3/mk3wnrewiNjn7KUViSVaQHe0iz5JUV21bKO4dPLYltBsl2C78LQrYIvoZ3oYNgeGk@@iM3tf1CZwlXJ9OvwzqKeLgw6xHY4O@Ha9TczkEUCKRRy7IVoPH3oRQ/J87@fPLUuT8AQ):

```py
import re
regex = r"^.*?/([^/]*)/?$"
text = "/tennis/qatar/atp-doha-2009/hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l/"
print(re.findall(regex, text))
```

Result: `['hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l']`

Answer (score 1):

For a more pythonic approach, you can also use:

```
"/tennis/qatar/atp-doha-2009/hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l/".split('/')[-2]
```

[str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) outputs a list of words split using the provided delimiter (in this case, `'/'`). So to break down the above statement,

```
s = "/tennis/qatar/atp-doha-2009/hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l/".split('/')

print(s)
>> ['', 'tennis', 'qatar', 'atp-doha-2009', 'hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l', '']

print(s[-2])
>> 'hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```py
s = "/tennis/qatar/atp-doha-2009/hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l/" 
s = "/".join(s.split("/")[-2:])  # Equivalent to your regex, with replace
s = s.rstrip("/")  # to remove the last slash
```

Answer (score 0):

This would require another step but you could essentially make your string an object, and from there you could just use list comprehension to remove the last character from the string.

`url = "hernych-jan-monfils-gael-S8Lm3D4l/"`

`url = url[:-1]`
That would remove your string but I'm sure there are other ways that could do it in 1 line